# Clojurescript interop with ProseMirror

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop, prose-mirror

I would like to add a modified ProseMirror editor to a figwheel-main-based Clojurescript project. After setting up a small experimental project, I'm just trying to reproduce this nonfunctional editor from the [ProseMirror guide](https://prosemirror.net/docs/guide/).

```js
import {schema} from "prosemirror-schema-basic"
import {EditorState} from "prosemirror-state"
import {EditorView} from "prosemirror-view"

let state = EditorState.create({schema})
let view = new EditorView(document.body, {state})
```

I set up a figwheel-main project from the template and added a few lines of code:

```clj
(ns ^:figwheel-hooks miraj.core
  (:require
    ...
   ["prosemirror-schema-basic" :as pm-schema-basic]
   ["prosemirror-state" :as pm-state :refer [EditorState]]
   ["prosemirror-view" :as pm-view :refer [EditorView]]
...
(set! *warn-on-infer* true)
...
(let [schema pm-schema-basic/schema
      editor-state (.create ^js/pm-state.EditorState EditorState #js {:schema schema})
      view (pm-view/EditorView. (.-body js/document) editor-state)])
```

The `let` is outside any other function -- I'm just trying to get the interop working to create some objects. This compiles without errors or warnings. An error is thrown at the browser console when it tries to load,

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.plugins')`

and the `view` is never created. `goog.object`'s `get` function shows that the `editor-state` does contain an empty `plugins` value, `#js []`.

What is the problem causing the failure to construct the `EditorView` object?